# Save Cognos report as .xlsx on local drive

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to save a Cognos report as a .xlsx file to a local drive, and how to do it.
We are using CA 11.1.6, on-premise.

Who can help me out?

Thanks in advance,
Edwin

Comment: If you're asking about saving report output as a .xlsx file, see C'est Moi's answer.  If you want to save the report definition as a .xlsx file, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You do it via the run as menu option.  If you are editing a report, there's a button for run as.  If the report is saved, it exists as a menu item on the context menu.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/c_cr_rptstd_intrd_producing_reports_inexcel_format.html

[image]