# Scheduling a monthly report - save to local drive

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

At the moment, our scheduled monthly reports are saved at the Cognos Server. However, I wonder if there is a way to save them to a local drive, as a .xlsx-file.
How can I achieve this, using CA 11.1.6 on-premise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742246/save-cognos-report-as-xlsx-on-local-drive but with some clarification.  It's better to update the other question.

Comment: And if this is legitimately a different question, there's not enough information.  What OS is Cognos running on?  What do you mean by "local drive"?  Is that local to the Cognos server or local to the client?